# Formatação de moeda

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho o seguinte script no meu HTML, o que ele faz é simplesmente checar uma checkbox se ela está ou não selecionada e no caso de estar adicionar um valor, a minha dúvida é, como fazer para esse valor ser formatado em moeda? Por exemplo ao em vez de aparecer 400,00 ou 1.455,80 ele aparece tudo junto como um número inteiro no caso 400 e 145580, como fazer para mostrar os valores em reais?

Script:

```js
function check() {
  var basic = 0;
  var add = 0;  

 
  if(document.getElementById("cl45").checked) {
    add += 145580;  
  }
  if(document.getElementById("trigger").checked) {
    add += 40000;
  }
  var p = basic + add;
    
   
  var price ="R$ " + p; 
  document.getElementById('total2').innerHTML = price;  
 }

check();
```

Comment: `price.toFixed(2)` Isso que você queria?

Comment: Não sei, comecei a trabalhar com js agora, vou dar uma pesquisada sobre isso, valeu.

Comment: Qual a razão desse valor com virgula no script add += 400,00; Porque não entra com valor que o javascript requer para calculos, ou seja 400.00 com ponto decimal?

Comment: Esse valor será exibido para o usuário, a ideia é que quando ele marque uma checkbox adicione um valor a um campo visível, de forma que algumas checkboxs adicionam 400,00 e outras 1.455,80, gostaria que o usuário pode-se visualizar a formatação em real comum e não que aparecesse "1455.8" ou "400".

Comment: dá para postar o html? esse script não está completo, fica dificil reproduzir um exemplo que possamos testar

Comment: Não é necessário, estou dando uma olhada em outra pergunta semelhante acredito que as repostas de lá podem me ajudar, já que essa minha pergunta foi duplicada. Se eu não conseguir qualquer coisa abro outra pergunta especificando melhor o meu problema, mas obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: veja se a minha resposta ajuda

Comment: não se deve alterar a pergunta porque dai a resposta fica meio sem sentido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function check() {
      var basic = 0;
      var add = 0;  

      add += 1455.80;
      
      var p = (basic + add).toFixed(2);
      
      var result = p.toString();
      
     //substitui separador decimal ponto por virgula
     result=result.replace(".", ",");
     //a regex abaixo coloca um ponto a esquerda de cada grupo de 3 digitos desde que não seja no inicio do numero
     result = result.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
     
     var price ="R$ " + result;
     
     document.getElementById('total2').innerHTML = price; 

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="trigger" onclick="check()">

<span id="total2"></span>
```

> Todas as linguagens tem como padrão o americano para inteiros e decimais, ou seja, você não vai conseguir fazer o cálculo corretamente, se houver valores decimais, se não trocar a vírgula pelo ponto.

Comment: Funcionou para os 400,00 tem como fazer algo semelhante para 1.455,80? da forma que está agora o número  é expresso "145.580,00".

Comment: Funcionou, tudo certo muito obrigado.